# Не идет makemigrations. Проблема (( Как быть?

Tags: python, django

Учусь. Не получается сделать makemigration выдает такую ошибку

```
(test_django) F:\django\test_django\courses_django>python manage.py makemigrations
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "F:\django\test_django\courses_django\lesson_sixth\urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . views import list
ImportError: cannot import name 'list' from 'lesson_sixth.views' (F:\django\test_django\courses_django\lesson_sixth\views.py)
```

Вот views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from .models import Human


class List(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'human_list.html'
    def get(self, request):
        all_humans = Human.objects.all() # все сотрудники
        the_first_two = Human.objects.all()[:2]
        #first_two = Human.objects.all()filter(company='gogle')[:4] # Комбинирование запросов
        workers_gogle = Human.objects.filter(company='gogle')
        filtered = Human.objects.filter(birth__year=1976) # сотрудники 1976 года рождения
        # one_worker = Human.objects.get(pk=1)
        ordered = Human.objects.all().ordered_by('birth')
        sorted = Human.objects.filter(birth__year__gte=1950).ordered_by('birth')
        sorted_salary = Human.objects.filter(salary__gte=100, salary__lte=3000).ordered_by('-salary')

        ctx = {
            'all_humans' : all_humans,
            'workers_gogle' : workers_gogle,
            #'one_worker' : one_worker,
            'filtered' : filtered,
            'first_two' : first_two,
            'ordered' : ordered,
            'sorted' : sorted,
            'sorted_salary' : sorted_salary
        }
        return render(request , self.template_name , ctx)
# Create your views here.
```

Где копать не могу разобраться...((

Comment: Понятно что не может List перекинуть. Вопрос почему ? И как это сделать ??

Comment: Текст ошибки надо вставлять текстом, а не изображением.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev исправил

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev все верно Сергей - проблема как Вы и сказал в регистре...  Спасибо огромное..

Comment: На Stackoverflow принято [отмечать решением ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), которые помогли.

Answer (score 1):

Python чувствителен к регистру символов. `List` и `list` - это два разных имени. Копать надо в учебнике.

Comment: Да самое интересное что в видео уроке у тренера все работает...((

Comment: Вот такие они качественные, видео-уроки.